# Relocating a toilet without weaking floor joists

Tags: plumbing, structure

Can I drill a 4" hole in 2" x 10" floor joists 3' 6" from end of wall? I'm located in Ontario Canada if this is relevant.

Comment: I assume you mean a hole in the middle of the joist, right? This link claims 3-3/4 inches max hole for a 2x12 joist: https://www.familyhandyman.com/floor/how-to-drill-through-floor-joists/view-all